Stable curve over a genus $g$ surface with $n$ marked points
I am reading the chapter 23 of Clay institute monograph on mirror symmetry. This is Exercise 23.4.2 from the book. Let $(\Sigma, p_1, \dots, p_n)\in \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ be a stable curve of genus $g$ and $n$ marked points. We have a natural forgetful map $f: \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n+1}\to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ where we forget a marked point and then stabilize.

They claim $p_1$ represents a point in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n+1}$, i.e a genus $g$ curve with $n+1$ marked points.
Let $N$ be a node of $\Sigma$. Then $N$ also corresponds to an element of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n+1}$.

Consider the first case, $p_1\in \Sigma$. If $q\in \Sigma$ is a smooth point of $\Sigma$ apart from $p_i$, then we have $$f((\Sigma, p_1, \dots, p_n, q))=(\Sigma, p_1, \dots, p_n)$$ But if $q=p_1$ then this won't work as the marked points need to be distinct. I'm not sure what to do in this case. I think I have to attach a sphere bubble somewhere, but I'm not sure where and what should be the $(n+1)$-th marked point.
In the case $N$ is a node, I think this one we just replace $N$ with a pinched sphere joining the two components containing the node. Then the new marked point should just be any point on the sphere.
Is this correct? How should I think about this? This is kind of trial and error for me at this point. I want to know how to systematically think about it.
